# Ring with reload-wrap in Emacs Cider REPL

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

When starting a Ring server from within an Emacs Cider REPL via reload-wrap, the REPL blocks. What can I do in order to have this code-reloading feature during development and being able to keep on working with the Cider REPL at the same time.

Aditionally, after cancelling the running server "process" from within the REPL by hitting C-c C-C, I cannot restart it on the same port, I'm getting the "address already in use" error.

I know this is possible with Stuart Sierra's component system. Is this the only way to go or is there maybe a simpler solution?

Answer (score 3):

When you start your ring server (I guess using jetty) you are not telling it to not join the current thread to the running server. You need to add `join?` option set to `false`:

```
(run-jetty my-handler {:join? false})
```

You should also bind the return value of this expression which is the server instance, so you can stop it later:

```
(def my-server (run-jetty my-handler {:join? false}))
;; some time later
(.stop my-server)
```

Stopping the server will close the server socket and make it available for future server instances.

Answer (score 2):

Simplier solution, to store web-server same wasy as component does somewhere in dev/user.clj. And configure `cider-refresh-fn` variable to start and stop web-server. 
Actually, idea is the same as in component approach, however you don't have to use it,